# EJB Endpoint Interface - Is client 'in VM'?

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jvm, ejb

As a beginner of SLSB EJB, I understand that accessing them locally (through Local Business Interface) is more efficient than remotely.

When an EJB is accessed through an Endpoint, is it being accessed remotely or locally?

This is in the context of accessing the EJB through JAX-RS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A webservice endpoint is neither local nor remote.  It is its own client view.

That said, the overhead from remote is primarily due to marshalling/demarshalling arguments for pass-by-value semantics of parameters and return types.  The webservice views will require the same, so you should expect slower performance than local, which uses pass-by-reference.  Whether or not a webservice view is faster or slower than remote depends on the webservices and remoting implementations.

Comment: Can you expand more? Is RMI protocol being used in Web Service to access EJB?

Comment: No, RMI is not used for webservices; the specific webservice technology is used.  For example, for JAX-WS, you have to marshall arguments/return values using e.g. SOAP, which is not cheap, the same as marshalling using e.g. RMI-IIOP is not cheap.

Comment: So there is only 1 JVM? And I guess this performancy penalty is for the sake of security?

Comment: No, there may be more than one JVM; however, if there is a single JVM, the remote, webservice, etc. views might be able to optimize the copy of paramter and return values.  No, security is not the primary overhead; the primary overhead is marshalling/demarshalling parameter and return values (e.g., converting ArrayList<String> to a byte stream or XML elements, and then from a byte stream or XML elements back into a ArrayList<String>).

Comment: How can I design to have only one JVM?

Comment: That's vendor-, topology-, and technology-specific question.